# Why does my MacBook's trackpad still function even when I have disabled it?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

The trackpad on my old MacBook Pro 2012 has an "erratic cursor dance issue" and it randomly scrolls, swipes and clicks everywhere.

I disabled the trackpad through

`Apple menu > System Preferences > Accessibility > Interacting > Mouse & Trackpad> Ignore trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present`.

But when I use my wireless mouse (a "**Universal wireless USB mouse**" which works properly), the trackpad still functions, which means it scrolls, swipes, and clicks everywhere.

Are there any other ways by which I can completely disable the trackpad?

Comment: I know what has damaged the trackpad, and it is not caused by swollen battery. Nevertheless, I'm not trying to fix the trackpad, I'm trying to completely disable it.

Comment: Have you tried a wired mouse? Perhaps the circuitry needs to sense a physical connection from a mouse to disable the internal trackpad. Similarly, macOS may sense the presence _of another trackpad_ when using an external wireless trackpad and disable the internal trackpad through software. This is just guesswork on my part, but may help figure out what's going on. In the end, physically detaching the internal trackpad from the logic board may be the only solution.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to find a wired mouse and try it out and see whether it makes a difference.

Regarding physically detaching the trackpad, I have actually tried it but somehow the keyboard gets disabled too. I don't know why.

Comment: Any USB mouse will work. Does not need to be Apple branded.